# pass the context on to an inner function

Tags: javascript

Here is the code:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
    element.tooltipster({
        content: '',
        theme: 'validation-notify',
        arrowColor: '#d9534f',
        contentAsHTML: true,
        functionBefore: generateContent
    });
}

function generateContent() {
    var formField = formCtrl[element];
    var i = 0;
}
```

The above code is broken because formCtrl and element are not available in `generateContent`. Now, I realize that I could use:

```
functionBefore: generateContent.bind({formCtrl: formCtrl, element: element})
```

and then in `generateContent` I could reference them by

```
this.element
```

I could also just declare generateContent inside of link. Is there any better way of doing this? Like is there anyway of binding generateContent to the entire context within link, so something like:

```
functionBefore: generateContent.bind(this)
```

(except in this case `this` is undefined)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Like is there anyway of binding generateContent to the entire context within link

Nope, the functions are lexically scoped and they remember the environment in which they are created. We cannot access those information, as they are implementation specific.

But what you can do is, make the `generateContent` function to accept all the parameters it needs and you can define `functionBefore`, like this

```
...
functionBefore: generateContent.bind(this, formCtrl, element)
...

function generateContent(formCtrl, element) {
    var formField = formCtrl[element];
    var i = 0;
}
```

Here, `generateContent.bind(this, formCtrl, element)` creates a new function object which when invoked, will have the context as the `link` function's `this` and two parameters `formCtrl` and `element` by default.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is make `generateContent` a function factory

```
function link(scope, element, attrs, formCtrl) {
        element.tooltipster({
            content: '',
            theme: 'validation-notify',
            arrowColor: '#d9534f',
            contentAsHTML: true,
            functionBefore: generateContent(fromCtrl, element) // pass here
        });
    }

function generateContent(fromCtrl, element) {
    return function() { // return a new function
        // use fromCtrl and element and do real work here
        var formField = formCtrl[element];
        var i = 0;
    }
}
```